# how to render tilted images in html or css or javascript ..?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, image

Is there a way to render an image tilted in html or css or JavaScript or php or anything else.... ?? And i know this can be done by first making a tilted image in Photoshop and then rendering it on the screen..... i would like to know if there is some other way to do this... i heard this is possible in JavaScript.... is it true..? If it is true, i would like a little explanation on such JavaScript........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plugin might help
[jquery rotate](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-rotate/)

Answer (score 4):

For a purely browser-based way to do this, one approach would be to use [CSS3 transforms](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-2d-transforms/) which can be used to rotate and skew images. Another would be to render the image using SVG, which again supports rotation and skew. Third way to do it would be to draw it with JS on a canvas.

These canvas and CSS3 approaches will work in modern browsers, at least in Opera 10, Firefox 4, Safari 4 and Chrome. SVG can be used in IE as well with assist from some libraries.

Comment: how do we achieve it using java script.......?? i have seen a code somewhere in the net but couldn't make out how to use it.......?